# In what order to update to SVN revisions?

Tags: wordpress, svn

I recently started working with SVN, I am using it in combination with Wordpress.

I just made a number of updates to Wordpress and to some plugins, and I would like to know in what order I need to update, or whether it even matters.

Here is what I did:

Locally on my computer:

1. svn delete folder xyz
2. commit the deletion
3. add a new folder by the same name
4. svn add the folder
5. svn commit

Now if I log in to our development server, do I just to "svn update" ?

Or do I need to go through the various versions by updating to specific version numbers?

The reason I ask, is because I have had one or two tree conflicts in the past where I got:

> Tree conflict (local dir unversioned, incoming dir add upon update) for location wp-content/plugins/ExamplePlugin/ExampleSubDir

Does my workflow lead to such errors? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow is fine, and yes, you would just perform a single `svn update` on the other computer to get fully up-to-date.

The workflow you describe would produce a tree conflict if you happened to have an *unversioned* folder named "xyz" in the same location as the one you just committed (which is what the error says in the parenthetical remark).  You should remove that unversioned folder and then let SVN add that folder itself (via the call to `update`).

If you haven't already, it might be worth reviewing some of [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) to ensure you understand [the fundamentals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html).